# PreferenceMatchers in Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I want to perform a click on an item in my preference activity. I have tried following code,

```
onData(withKey("preference-key")).perform(click());
```

But it throws an exception like,

> Caused by:
>   android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: Multiple
>   Ambiguous Views found for matcher is assignable from class: class
>   android.widget.AdapterView

How can I properly perform a click on this item?

Comment: could you add xml file of your layout? it would be easier to notice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `AmbiguousViewMatcherException` as you notice means that you have at least two views with the same `id`, `key`, `text`, `contentDescription` etc.

Your code tells me that you're trying to write `AdapterView` test like you would have one view, so you try to use `onData` matcher like it was `onView` matcher. Sorry, but `AdapterView` tests are never as simple.

Instead of

```
onData(withKey("preference-key")).perform(click());
```

write code like this

```
onData(anything())
  .inAdapterView(allOf(
      isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.fragment1)), 
      withId(R.id.listview)))
    .atPosition(4)
    .perform(click());
```

Look for `AmbiguousViewMatcherException` Espresso issues on StackOverflow. It's quit often problem, maybe someone had view like yours.

Comment: Then, if they cannot be used like `onView` matchers, what are Espresso's [PreferenceMatchers](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/matcher/PreferenceMatchers) good for?